# How to draw a round picture Pixijs

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

I need to draw a picture in a circle, or a round picture with a given height and width. I couldn't find any suitable answers. So far, we managed to do this, but the fact is that this is a texture and it is drawn many times and the position does not change.

```
const test = new Graphics()
test.lineStyle(0,0x000000);
const options = {
  width: 25,
  height: 25,
}
const baseTexture = new BaseTexture(url,options);
const texture = new Texture(baseTexture);
test.beginTextureFill({texture});
test.drawCircle(0, 0, 15);
test.endFill();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't just import an image or sprite sheet of a circular picture, then create a sprite object using that texture.

```
PIXI.Loader.shared.add("img/circle.png");
var circleImage=new PIXI.Sprite(
    PIXI.Loader.shared.resources["img/circle.png"].texture
);
```

Comment: because u can get image from server (user avatar for example)...